# Is $\tau_{d_1}$ equal to $\tau_{d_\infty}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$X=C[0,1]$

$f,g\in X$ ,   $d_{\infty}(f,g)=\max|f(x)-g(x)|,\mbox{ for}\quad 0\le x\le 1$

$d_1(f,g)=\int^1_0|f(x)-g(x)|dx$

since $d_1(f,g)\le\int^1_0d_{\infty}(f,g)dx$

$d_1(f,g)\le d_{\infty}(f,g)$

Let $A\in \tau_{d_1}\rightarrow\forall f\in A,\exists r>0:B_{d_1}(f,r)\subset A$.

How can I continue?

Comment: @Nameless I want to show if it is $\tau_{d_\infty}=\tau_{d_1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you can construct easily $f_n\to 0$ in $\tau_1$ but $f_n\not\to 0$ in $\tau_\infty$. $f_n$ will be a spike tall and narrow.